# DocuSign - Unable to set Routing Order properly

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

We use NodeJS integration to get signatures from 3 different signers. Agent is always In-Person signer. Customer and coCustomer can be In-Person (Embed) or Email. I am adding "clientUserId" if one of them is In-Person. But when I do email sign for customer, they get the email right when the API is requested, this gives Agent no chance to sign and the customer sees a blank pdf with no custom Fields.

When I add "routingOrder" higher than Agent's, the customer gets and email with a link that leads to an embed where the customer can add fields. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think you don't have fields set for all your recipients. You are describing the situation of "free form signing" where the customer doesn't have pre-selected fields (tabs). You need to add tabs to the customer in your code. (if you show your code here - it would help us help you).